# Use a child element to drag a parent element

Tags: javascript, draggable

I want to make something like navigation bar that can move whole element, without allowing dragging anywhere on the parent entire element to control the dragging. For example:

```
<div class="undraggable">
    <div class="draggable"></div>
    content
</div>
```

*Dragging on a title bar drags the whole window that it is contained within, but dragging elsewhere on the window container does not drag the window.*

I tried to use [dragresize](http://www.twinhelix.com/javascript/dragresize/demo/) but I can't make only draggable (don't want resizable) object with his code.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743513/488802 which limits the parts of the parent are draggable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Register your mousedown handler on the drag controller (e.g. the title bar of the window).
2. When you are dragging, update the position of a different element (e.g. the window wrapper).

I have an example of this here:
http://phrogz.net/js/PhrogzWerkz/WerkWin.html

*If you need this to work with a specific library—like a jQuery UI library—then please edit your question to say say.*

### Simpler Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VCQuN/1/

```html
<div class="window">
  <div class="titlebar">Hello, World!</div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Window <b>Content!</b></p>
  </div>
</div>​
```

```js
// For each item with a `window` class…
var windows = document.querySelectorAll('.window');
[].forEach.call(windows,function(win){

  // …find the title bar inside it and do something onmousedown
  var title = win.querySelector('.titlebar');
  title.addEventListener('mousedown',function(evt){

    // Record where the window started
    var real = window.getComputedStyle(win),
        winX = parseFloat(real.left),
        winY = parseFloat(real.top);

    // Record where the mouse started
    var mX = evt.clientX,
        mY = evt.clientY;

    // When moving anywhere on the page, drag the window
    // …until the mouse button comes up
    document.body.addEventListener('mousemove',drag,false);
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',function(){
      document.body.removeEventListener('mousemove',drag,false);
    },false);

    // Every time the mouse moves, we do the following 
    function drag(evt){
      // Add difference between where the mouse is now
      // versus where it was last to the original positions
      win.style.left = winX + evt.clientX-mX + 'px';
      win.style.top  = winY + evt.clientY-mY + 'px';
    };
  },false);
});
​
```

Comment: thank so much your example is very perfect but it a bit too hard for an amateur like me to understand.

Comment: @hsgu Then you should not accept my answer until you get the one that solves your problem. However! See my edit for a simpler example.

Comment: sorry, I'm newbie and diffident. But now I think I can get it thank you so much.

Comment: thank you so much sir !
removeEventListener onmouseup also otherwise you are adding dublicate mouseup event listeners on every mousedown
I also combined following script to save/restore window position http://jsfiddle.net/v685v9t6/862/

Comment: This is not drag'n'drop, this is moving something around with a custom solution.
Drag'n'drop is implemented at the operating system level, it allows interactions between different softwares.

Comment: @ChristopheQuintard That is true, but I wonder why you mention this. The OP doesn't ask about drag and drop, the question isn't tagged as such, and my answer does not mention it. Further, drag and drop does not have to be implemented at the OS level. Many JavaScript libraries exist for it (I've written some myself).

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for something like this but in jquery ui due to the fact I am already using it in my project so if you already using JQUERY UI you can identify the handle you wish to drag with.
here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VPMFs/

```
<style>
.undraggable{height:500px;width:500px;background:blue;}
.draggable{height:100px;width:100px;background:white;}
</style>
<div class="undraggable">
<div class="draggable">drag me!</div>
</div>

<script>
$('.undraggable').draggable({handle: '.draggable'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have an attribute draggable="true" in parent element and draggable="false" in all child elements. Now if you drag any of the child element or parent element , you drag will work properly.
If you don't add draggable="false" in image tag, your drag and drop feature wont work properly.
[image: Drag and drop with nested elements]

```
<span className="dragelement cp"  draggable={true} 
onDragStart={(event)=>drag(event)} onDragEnd={(event)=>dragEnd(event)} 
id= {'drag'+el.type+index+idx}>
    <div>{m.a}</div>  
    {m.img && <img draggable={false} src={m.img} height="70px" width="100px" />  } 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery UI draggable feature:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

you can build a custom download of jQuery UI to only get the components you need (draggable and it's dependencies) here: http://jqueryui.com/download.

It has a lot of configuration options - your wording is a little ambiguous but I think you may want the handle option: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle