# How to implement drag and drop so dragging child element will drag whole parent element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a media import plugin for wordpress. I'm trying to implement a drag and drop feature to reorder media elements(audio and/or images) that the user has imported. I have a `<div>` tag(we'll call these *media divs*) that holds up to three other `<span>`, `<img>`, or `<audio>` tags. So I have all the media assets that have been imported displayed in a line and would like to be able to drag and drop to reorder the *media divs*. I have no problem implementing the basic drag and drop using html5. My problem is that right now when I click on the media child elements(`<audio>` or `<img>`) inside the *media divs*, the child element is the target of the drag event. Is there any way I can reset the target of the drag event to be the parent element so I drag the whole *media div* and not just the media element? I've looked into `e.stopPropogation()` and read up on bubbling, and capturing but every way I've tried to utilize those, it doesn't solve my problem. Is there something I'm missing? I would prefer to avoid jQuery if possible and definitely can't use any libraries or frameworks. 
 **TL;DR: How can I make the parent element the target of a drag event when a child element is clicked?**

```
<div class="npr-import-media npr-import-audio npr-import-images" id="media-container">

    <div class="npr-import-media-container" draggable="true">
        <audio src="<?php echo $audio->format->mp4->{'$text'}; ?>" controls></audio>
        <span class="npr-media-delete">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="npr-import-image-container npr-import-media-container" draggable="true">
        <img class="npr-import-image" src="<?php echo $image->src; ?>" >
        <span class="npr-import-image-caption"><?php echo $image->caption->{'$text'} ?></span>
        <span class="npr-media-delete">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="npr-import-add-media npr-import-media-container">
        Add Media+
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the HTML portion of my code. There is originally some more php functionality to loop through the original source material to display all of the media elements being imported in from the original article, but I don't think it's necessary to include that.

Comment: Why don't you just make the parent element draggable?

Comment: @MustafaShujaie The parent element (the _media div_) is draggable. I set `draggable = true`. But when I click on the child of the _media div_, it must be draggable as well, because it becomes the object being dragged and not the whole _media div_.

Comment: Please insert your HTML markup

Comment: As I understood you want to reorder the media div elements, right? Also you don't need the child elements to be draggable. When you click on child elements and start dragging the event will be bubbled to the parent element and will be handled by the event handler assigned to it.

Comment: @MustafaShujaie that's what I thought as well but no matter how many ways I try to enable/disable bubbling or capturing it doesn't change anything. And no matter how I try to use `stopPropagation()`, it doesn't change anything. I think now I'm going to use capturing and at the beginning of the `ondragstart` event, I will check if `ev.target.className` is what I want. If it isn't I will just exit the function and let capturing take care of the rest.

Comment: Now I think I understood your problem :), please see if my answer solves your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the handler for `ondragstart` event to return false, like below:

```
<div class="npr-import-media npr-import-audio npr-import-images" id="media-container">
    <div class="npr-import-image-container npr-import-media-container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;">
        <img class="npr-import-image" src="img.jpg" >
        <span class="npr-import-image-caption">Caption</span>
        <span class="npr-media-delete">X</span>
    </div>

    <div class="npr-import-add-media npr-import-media-container">
        Add Media+
    </div>
</div>
<script>
function drag(e) {
    console.log(e);
}
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(i = 0 ; i < images.length; i++) 
    images[i].ondragstart = function() { return false; }
</script>
```

On console output you can see:

```
>> DragEvent {isTrusted: true, dataTransfer: DataTransfer, screenX: 66, screenY: 161, clientX: 66…}
```

**UPDATE**
By setting drag event handlers on the parent elements either by html attributes as above or attaching event listeners by code as below:

```
document.getElementById('draggable').addEventListener('dragstart', function(e) {
   console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: That's close to what I need, but now when you try to drag on the picture, nothing happens at all. Is there a way for this to bubble up to the top so the parent element becomes the target?

Answer (score 9):

I just came across this issue as well. I resolved it without javascript by simply adding draggable="false" to each child element.

```
<div class="npr-import-image-container npr-import-media-container" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" style="border:1px solid blue;padding:10px;">
    <img draggable="false" class="npr-import-image" src="img.jpg" >
    <span draggable="false" class="npr-import-image-caption">Caption</span>
    <span draggable="false" class="npr-media-delete">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was just in the same problem and couldn't work around img tag, so switched to div.

You can use

```
<div style="background-image: url('img.jpg')"></div>
```

instead of

```
<img class="npr-import-image" src="img.jpg" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar situation. I had a parent with two children (gripper and content), and needed the whole parent to be dragged when gripper was dragged, but no dragging when content was dragged

Make the parent and content draggable, BUT in the content's `ondragstart`, cancel the drag, that way the drag will start only when the mouse is not in the content (but in the gripper)

```js
  const catchAndPreventDragStartEventGettingToParent = (event) => {
    //prevent drag behaviour in content item, 
    console.log("no dragging");
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  const dragStart = (event) => {
    console.log("dragging");
    //event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "move";
    //event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", JSON.stringify(data));
  };
```

```css
#parent{
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color:teal;
}

.gripper{
  margin: 1rem;
  padding:1rem;
  background-color: linen;
}
.content{
  margin: 1rem;
  padding:1rem;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div 
  id="parent"
  draggable = true
  ondragstart= "dragStart(event)">
  <span class ="gripper">Gripper:</span>
  <span
    class = "content"   
    draggable= true 
    ondragstart="catchAndPreventDragStartEventGettingToParent(event)">
    CONTENT
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but I find out an easy way to get the closest parent with a specific css class.

Based on your example try to use

```
    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
    let desiredTarget = e.target.closest('.npr-import-image-container');
    console.log(desiredTarget);
     // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Orion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52023274/13931027), when dragging an element across the page, the [immediate user selection](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#immediate-user-selection) will change once the mouse encounters a draggable element. Once this change happens, it will fire a `dragleave` event for the previous [current target element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dnd.html#current-target-element), and update it to the current element you are hovering over - essentially the new drop target. Since images (and links) are draggable elements by default, this can cause issues when they are children of your drag-and-drop solution.

This is why `draggable="false"` on images will work to disable the native functionality; however, I have found that applying the `pointer-events: none` CSS property to the images will work as well. Although, if you use the CSS solution, you might need JS to toggle that style if you want a hover effect on the images themselves. Wanted to provide this information just in case it would not be possible to update the image's attributes.